# What are some good papers or resources for aspect extraction and opinion modelling from video or audio?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction, sentiment-analysis, data-mining

I am quite new to deep learning. I just finished the deep learning specialization by Professor Andrew NG and Deep Learning AI. Now, my professor (instructor) has advised me to look into some classic papers for aspect extraction and opinion mining from video. Could anyone suggest me some resources where I can get started? Can anyone suggest some papers I should read? Maybe a course or a book or some links to descriptive sessions. Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The paper [A Multi-modal Approach to Fine-grained Opinion Mining on Video Reviews](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.13362.pdf) could be useful for your purposes, although I have read only the abstract

> Despite the recent advances in opinion mining for written reviews, few works have tackled the problem on other sources of reviews. In light of this issue, **we propose a multimodal approach for mining fine-grained opinions from video reviews** that is able to determine the aspects of the item under review that are being discussed and the sentiment orientation towards them. Our approach works at the sentence level without the need for time annotations and uses features derived from the audio, video and language transcriptions of its contents. We evaluate our approach on two datasets and show that leveraging the video and audio modalities consistently provides increased performance over text-only baselines, providing evidence these extra modalities are key in better understanding video reviews.

and looked at some of the diagrams and figures in the paper.